# damage to party wall that extends above my home - who is responsible?

Tags: property

the wall that separates our home from our neighbours needs repair. however while this is a party wall, their home is uphill from ours, and therefore this part of the wall only forms part of their house, ie it is above our roofline.

as such we're unsure whose responsibility the repairs are. is it 50/50 as it's a shared wall, or does the fact that this bit of the wall is only part of their house mean they need to fix it?

thanks

Comment: this will depend on where in the world the properties are, e.g. even between England and Scotland there are different rules